# Regular Expression: Not equal to Account and not begin with Account/

Tags: regex

Regular Expression: Not equal to Account and not begin with Account/

How do I express that in a regular expression?

Thank You.

Comment: Which language do you like to write this ?

Answer (score 3):

If your implementation supports [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can do this with a negated look-ahead assertion:

```
^(?!Account($|/))
```

The same can be done with a negated look-behind assertion. Otherwise, if you just can use basic syntax, you will probably do something like this:

```
^($|[^A]|(A($|[^c]|c($|[^c]|c($|[^o]|o($|[^u]|u($|[^n]|n($|[^t]|t[^/]))))))))
```

But maybe it suffices if you try to match either *equal to `Account`* or *begins with `Account/`* and invert the result of the match.

Comment: Is a "look-around" required here?

Comment: Shouldn't the `^` be outside of the `(?!…)`?

Comment: @pst: I’ve also posted a low-level solution.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the regex (for some regex flavors) `/^(Account$|Account\/)/` which only matches "Account" or things that begin with "Account/". Note the use of anchors (^ and $) as appropriate.

Why is the above regex the *opposite* of the question? In many cases of "not looking for" the outer-regex conditional can (and should) simply be a negation.

Answer (score 0):

This says 'If the line doesn't belong with Account or contain Account (I know redundant) then match the entire line:

(?! ^Account)(?! ^.*Account.*)^.*$